# Link that runs code to expand flash object fullscreen without refreshing

Tags: flash, hyperlink, fullscreen

I want to have a flash game with a link at the bottom that says "Fullscreen" and when you click it as though it was a link it will scale a flash object to be as big as your screen without stretching it, or refreshing it. My blog can be found at **bestjavascriptgames.blogspot.com** The link for fullscreen is **NOT** there right now because I don't want people asking about it. Also I have been trying out different display techniques so right now the menu only has 4 games available. It normally has more but for now it has 4.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the link is within the Flash object, this is easily achieved:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

fullscreenBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goFullscreen);
function goFullscreen(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have said, I will assume for the duration of my answer that the knowledge you desire is needed in the form of HTML.

Rather than a "link" (an <a href=""></a>), to prevent reloading what you need is a <span></span> or <a></a> (without an href.. not technically valid HTML) which has only an onclick attribute and any styling your site needs.

That onclick should run JavaScript that interfaces with your flash object, calling it's internal full-screen'ing routine(s). This comes without penalty of any reloading. I leave the rest as a research project on how to call into flash objects - there are plenty of examples on the web which you can adapt to your needs and I prefer not to guess at how to go about this for your particular flash object.

Comment: You can't launch a fullscreen Flash object without interacting with it, due to security restrictions. Going fullscreen must be the result of an interaction with the Flash.

Comment: @Marty Wallace  So what you are telling me is that nothing outside the flash object can interact with it? I've seen websites achieve this though. For instance, [link](http://y8.com) It allows you to resize the flash to nay size with a scaling bar. How do they do this?

Comment: @EtariPnoit That's not fullscreen, that's just the Flash object scaled to fit the window. Fullscreen would hide the browser navigation and taskbar.